# Enable a button on textarea value change

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have a textarea in my form. Now I want to enable a button once there is a change in the text of the textarea.

I tried using `onchange` event on the textarea, but, while using it, the browser wants me to click outside the textarea to enable the button, even though I changed some text in the textarea.

My requirement is to enable the button, the moment I change the text.

I have written this function `onclick` of the textarea:

```
function enableUpdateButton() {

    document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;

}
```

What change should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `onkeypress`, `onkeyup` or `onkeydown` attribute on your textarea instead of `onchange`. The `onchange` attribute is invoked when **focus** was changed from *textarea* to another element.

Answer (score 2):

```
function enableUpdateButton() {

    document.getElementById("button").disabled = false;

} 
document.getElementById('textareaId').onkeypress=enableUpdateButton();
```

Answer (score 0):

I use keyListeners for this requirements like this:

```
this.jt_Auftragsnummer.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {

     @Override
     public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
     // Do some stuff
     }
}
```

This works quite nice for me.